# Vector Notation of $\nabla\cdot\left(\left(\vec{v}\cdot\nabla\right)\vec{v}\right)$ where $0=\nabla\cdot\vec{v}$

Tags: vector-analysis, vector-fields, divergence-operator

I want a simplified way of writing the above expression in a clear way using vector notation. It is given that $\vec{v}$ has a divergence of 0. I’ve found that
$$\nabla\cdot\left(\left(\vec{v}\cdot\nabla\right)\vec{v}\right)=\left(\vec{v}\cdot\nabla\right)\left(\nabla\cdot\vec{v}\right)+\sum_{i=1}^{3}\sum_{j=1}^{3}\left(\frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_i}\right)\left(\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{3}\sum_{j=1}^{3}\left(\frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_i}\right)\left(\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j}\right)=Trace{\left(\left(\nabla\vec{v}\right)^2\right)}$$
To clarify,
$$\left(\vec{A}\cdot\nabla\right)\vec{B}=A_x\left(\frac{\partial\vec{B}}{\partial x}\right)+A_y\left(\frac{\partial\vec{B}}{\partial y}\right)+A_z\left(\frac{\partial\vec{B}}{\partial z}\right)$$

Comment: Why do you think there's a more compact way of writing out this identity?  Your expression $\text{Tr}\left ( \left (\nabla \vec{v}\right )^2 \right )$ is probably as compact as you're going to get this.

Comment: @Mnifldz I mainly want an expression which is easier to use in calculations. For that expression, you need to make the 3x3 vector gradient matrix, multiply it by itself, and then find its trace. I'd like something somewhat quicker. You know how the divergence of a vector field is the trace of its vector gradient matrix? I can't help but wonder if there's something similar to or better than that for this expression.